# Is there any way to use regex instead of exact string in Xtext grammar rules?

Tags: regex, dsl, xtext

Is it somehow possible to put regex instead of exact string into the Xtext grammar rule, e.g. when I want to make `+=` but also `+====` valid:

`AssignAdd:
    number1=Number "\+(=)+" number2=Number;`

Comment: Did you have a look at terminal rules instead of using a keyword

Comment: Yes I thought about it also, but wanted to solve it without new terminals. But probably it's the best way, so I will go for the terminals. Thank you for quick reply.

Comment: if you hate terminals, you can also write `"="+`